# What is the maximum of a set of random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm a bit confused by a problem I'm supposed to solve:

Given a sample of random variables $(X_1,...,X_n)$, uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,2\vartheta]$, $\vartheta>0$ and unknown. What value does the parameter $\gamma$ have to take for the estimator $$\theta_3=\gamma\left(\max_{i=1,...,n}X_i+\min_{j=1,...,n}X_j\right)$$
to be unbiased?

I reasoned something like $$\mathbb E\theta_3=\gamma\mathbb E\left(\max_{i=1,...,n}X_i+\min_{j=1,...,n}X_j\right)=2\gamma\mathbb EX_n=2\gamma\vartheta $$

and therefore $\gamma=\frac{1}{2}$. I'm pretty sure that's wrong though, especially considering that I'm not even sure what $$\max_{i=1,...,n}X_i$$ is supposed to mean - random variables are functions right?

($\mathbb E$ is supposed to be the expected value, I'm not very familiar with the terms used in english speaking countries).

Comment: Write your random variables as function of the sample point $\omega$, a point in the underlying sample space. Then the random variable "max" is given by $\max X_i(\omega) = \max(X_1(\omega), \dots, X_n(\omega))$

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. Not sure how to work with that, but at least I know where to start now.

Comment: The English term for $\mathbb{E}$ is "expected value."

Comment: wikipedia said expected value and mean mean the same thing, changed it though.

Comment: Mean, expected value, and expectation are all acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X= \max_{i=1,...,n} X_i$ is the function $X:\Omega \to \Bbb R$ which sends $\omega \in \Omega$ to $\max_{i=1,...,n} X_i(\omega)$.

The following simple symmetry argument shows that $\gamma=1/2$:

Consider the random variables $Y_i=2\theta - X_i$. Obviously, the $Y_i$ are also indepent and uniformly distributed on $[0,2\theta]$. Define $m=\Bbb E[\max_{i=1,...,n}X_i]$. Now, since $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ are distributed in the same way as $(X_1,...,X_n)$, we have also $m=\Bbb E[\max_{i=1,...,n}Y_i]$. But $$\max_{i=1,...,n}Y_i=\max_{i=1,...,n}2\theta - X_i=2\theta - \min_{i=1,...,n}X_i$$ yielding $$\Bbb E[\min_{i=1,...,n}X_i]=2\theta -\Bbb E[\max_{i=1,...,n}Y_i]=2\theta -m$$ Hence $$\Bbb E[\min_{i=1,...,n}X_i]+\Bbb E[\max_{i=1,...,n}X_i]=(2\theta-m)+m=2\theta$$

Comment: I get it, but I can't quite imagine how you'd get the idea for this - did you start form the assumption that it's $2\theta$ and worked backwards from there?

Comment: Symmetry! Here the symmetry $x\mapsto2\vartheta-x$ of the interval $(0,2\vartheta)$, which inverts maxs and mins and leaves the uniform distribution unchanged.

Comment: I thought I had gotten it for a sec, but... why is the EV the same for $\max X_i$ and $\max Y_i$ again?

Comment: @Cubic: Because they have the same distribution (namely the uniform distribution on $[0,2\theta]^n$) hence their respective maxima are identically distributed and their expectations coincide (since the expectation does only depend on the distribution).

Comment: @Dominik Just to make sure - a random variable is uniformly distributed in $[a,b]$ if it is linear in $[a,b]$ and constant $0$ otherwise, and $Y_i$ is still uniformly distributed in $[0,2\vartheta]$ because you just changed the slope, not the fact that it's linear in $[0,2\vartheta]$?